# How to insert <br> tag in ng-repeat angular-js after every 5 elements

Tags: angularjs

While Using ng-repeat , I need to print only 5 in a row

I have tried as shown below

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
        <br ng-if="($n+1)%5==0">
  </div> 

</div>
```

But all the rows are getting printed in a single row

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/474/

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap? @pawan

Comment: I am using Metronic Theme

Comment: please tell me in case i need to include any specific css ?

Comment: You are rendering `input` elements in `div` and bydefault `DIV` render as a `block` element. [Read about block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Answer (score 4):

You could have it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in names" style="display: inline">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
  <div ng-show="($index + 1) % 5 === 0">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/479/)

Comment: @FarooqKhan sorry I misinterpreted. Thanks for correcting. I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div ng-repeat="n in names">     
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>
 <br ng-if="($index+1)%5==0">
</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
        <div ng-if="($index+1)%5==0"><br></div>
  </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of break you can use `<p></p>` also

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["Emil1", "Tobias2", "Linus3","Emil4", "Tobias5", "Linus6","Emil7", "Tobias8", "Linus9","Emil10", "Tobias11", "Linus12","Emil13", "Tobias", "Linus"];
  $scope.selectedNames = [];
  
  $scope.select = function(name) {
      var index = $scope.selectedNames.indexOf(name);
      if(index < 0)
          $scope.selectedNames.push(name);
      else
          $scope.selectedNames.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
         <p ng-show="($index+1)%5==0"></p>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's decause your divs width are default 100%. Try to use bootstrap grid system instead:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="n in names" class="col-xs-2">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4yb539x/

Although you cannot split a row to 5 equal columns directly, only with a workaround with col offsets.